# does ios 5 support background audio in web.app? (need dev to test)

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, ios5, backgrounding

I'm hoping for a iOS dev with one of the iOS 5 betas installed to do me a huge favour! I don't have a dev account and know better than to install the beta as it is.

I want to know if iOS 5 supports playing background audio in web.app's. To avoid confusion, by that I mean websites that a user adds/runs to the homescreen, and have this set:

`<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">`

In iOS 4 & below, web apps stop playing audio when the app is closed by the user pressing the home button. Whereas if the website is visited in Safari, audio can continue in the background after closing. I want to know if this has changed, as web apps can run JIT/NitroScript in iOS 5.

If someone running the iOS beta (latest if possible) has one second to check this out, could they load the following URL in Safari, add to the homescreen, open from homescreen, play audio, press home and see if the audio continues to play? I'd very very much appreciate it.

http://jsfiddle.net/ooobo/znp3m/show/light/

(p.s. screw the nda, just hint at me :D)

Comment: I suggest you wait until it's out of beta in case anything changes in the final builds.

Comment: Fair, I'm not about to go building anything for this for that reason, I more want to know because I'm interested an curious. Still, this is unlikely to change in the final builds. I've heard rumours Web.app runs identical to Safari.app now, but nothing confirmed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirmed... audio DOES NOT play once home button is pressed. beta 6 used.

Steps used:loaded the following URL in Safari, add to the homescreen, open from homescreen, play audio, press home. Audio stopped

Comment: Thanks very much for checking this out Tammen! Disappointing result though, would love to see Apple make web apps at least equal to pages opened in Safari. Here's hoping it comes eventually